# Adapt code with months instead of with weeks

Tags: python, django

```
        start_week = start_date - datetime.timedelta(7)
        end_week = start_week + datetime.timedelta(7)

            while start_week < end_week:
                array = np.array([])
                count = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user__date_joined__range=[start_week, end_week])
                array = np.append(array, count)
                start_week = end_week + datetime.timedelta(1)
                end_end = start_week + datetime.timedelta(7)
```

This code works amazingly, because we consider the start date and a end date of a week. Week will always have 7 days, while the number of days in a month and in a year varie. How could we adapt this code so that it will work efficiently with months and years instead of with weeks?

Comment: I don't know what to try @AlexanderTyapkov

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the current month from today's date. With that, you can determine the number of days to add/subtract.

**Example**:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
current_year = today.year
current_month = today.month
daysdiff = 0
if current_month in [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]:
    daysdiff = 31
elif current_month == 2:
    # check if leap year
    if current_year % 4 == 0:
        if current_year % 100 == 0:
            if current_year % 400 == 0:
                daysdiff = 29
            else:
                daysdiff = 28
        else:
            daysdiff = 28
    else:
        daysdiff = 28
else:
    daysdiff = 30
```

You can then use the variable `daysdiff` to use in the further computations.

As a side note, you can use the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module which has `relativedelta` method which takes months as an argument to calculate based on current month.

**Example**:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# as an example, lets go back one month from `now`
prev_month_date = datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=1)
```

Comment: Could you show what it can looks like with `dateutils` and `relativedelta`?

Comment: You just have to adapt it to my code and I will accept your answer.

Comment: You should try that yourself. I have put the examples for that. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: As you wish Sachin, but I don't think it is a big deal for you.